# Show that ${{2m} \choose {m}} \leq \frac{2^{2m}}{\sqrt{2m}}$.

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, binomial-coefficients

The question is as it is in the title:

> Show that
>
> $${{2m} \choose {m}} \leq \frac{2^{2m}}{\sqrt{2m}}$$
>
> for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

I've had various attempts at this question but it never seems to lead anywhere fruitful. The hint we have been given is in the question is

> Consider the square of the product
>
> $$ \frac{(2m)!}{2^{2m}(m!)^2} = \frac{3 \times 5 \times 7 \times \dots \times (2m-1)}{2 \times 4 \times 6 \times \dots \times (2m)}. $$

From the hint it's not too hard to spot where one would go next - the LHS of the original question is disguised as some cheeky factorials - however induction keeps on failing for me and I'm struggling to see a more direct argument. Any light shed on this problem would be appreciated. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bit of an overkill but if it comes down to it you could always use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: Hint: I would start with $\frac{1}{2} \frac{2}{3}\ldots \frac{2m-1}{2m} = \frac{1}{2m}$. Decompose the LHS into $AB = \frac{1}{2m}$ where $A$ and $B$ are "similar" and play around with it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Show the stronger inequality
$${{2m} \choose {m}} <\frac{2^{2m}}{\sqrt{2m+1}}.$$
It is true for $m=1$. Induction step: for $m\geq 1$,
$$\frac{(2m+2)!}{2^{2m+2}((m+1)!)^2}=\frac{(2m)!}{2^{2m}(m!)^2}\cdot \frac{2m+1}{2m+2}< \frac{1}{\sqrt{2m+1}}\cdot \frac{2m+1}{2m+2}\stackrel{?}{\leq}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m+3}}.$$
So it remains to prove that
$$4m^2+8m+3=(\sqrt{2m+1}\sqrt{2m+3})^2\leq (2m+2)^2=4m^2+8m+4$$
which holds.

Comment: Very nice, this is exactly how I approached it initially but it never seemed to work out at the inductive step. It's interesting how a stronger result actually made the proof work.

Answer (score 6):

Now,
$$\tfrac{3\cdot5\cdot...\cdot(2m-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot...\cdot2m}=\sqrt{\tfrac{3(3\cdot5)(5\cdot7)...((2m-3)(2m-1))(2m-1)}{4\cdot4^2\cdot6^2\cdot...\cdot(2m-2)^2\cdot4m^2}}<\sqrt{\frac{3(2m-1)}{16m^2}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

This is an incomplete solution, maybe somebody else can see where to go from here.

Use induction with induction statement

$$P(m): {{2m} \choose {m}}\leq \dfrac{2^{2m}}{\sqrt{2m}}$$

Such that the base $(m=1)$ case is

$$P(1): {{2(1)} \choose {(1)}}\leq \dfrac{2^{2(1)}}{\sqrt{2(1)}}$$

This is easily shown because ${{2}\choose{1}} =2 =\dfrac{2\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\leq\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{2}}$ and we know $\sqrt{2}<{2}$. Then, assuming $P(m)$ is true, we must show $P(m+1)$ which states

$$P(m+1): {{2(m+1)} \choose {(m+1)}}\leq \dfrac{2^{2(m+1)}}{\sqrt{2(m+1)}}$$

Start with the left hand side

$$\begin{align}
{{2(m+1)} \choose {(m+1)}} &= \dfrac{(2(m+1))!}{(m+1)!(2(m+1)-(m+1))!}
\\
&=\dfrac{(2m+2)!}{(m+1)!(m+1)!}
\\
&=\dfrac{(2m+2)(2m+1)(2m)!}{(m+1)(m+1)m!m!}
\\
&=\dfrac{(2m+2)(2m+1)}{(m+1)(m+1)}\Bigg(\dfrac{(2m)!}{m!m!}\Bigg)
\\
&=\dfrac{(2m+2)(2m+1)}{(m+1)(m+1)}{{2m} \choose {m}}
\\
&\leq\dfrac{(2m+2)(2m+1)}{(m+1)(m+1)}\dfrac{2^{2m}}{\sqrt{2m}}
\\
&=\dfrac{2(m+1)(2m+1)}{(m+1)(m+1)}\dfrac{2^{2m}}{\sqrt{2m}}
\\
&=\dfrac{(2m+1)}{(m+1)}\dfrac{2^{2m+1}}{\sqrt{2m}}
\end{align}$$

Now, since $m \in \mathbb{N}$, it is obvious that

$$m^2(m +2)>1 \implies 2m^3 + 4m^2 >2 \implies 2m^3 + 4m^2 +2m >2m + 2$$

Then,

$$2m^3 + 4m^2 +2m >2m + 2 \implies (m^2+2m+1)(2m)>2(m+1) \implies (m+1)\sqrt{2m}>\sqrt{2(m+1)}$$

Now, since the denominator is larger, we can say

$$\begin{align}
{{2(m+1)} \choose {(m+1)}} &\leq\dfrac{(2m+1)}{(m+1)}\dfrac{2^{2m+1}}{\sqrt{2m}}
\\
&\leq(2m+1)\dfrac{2^{2m+1}}{\sqrt{2(m+1)}}
\end{align}$$